# How to move animatedsprite reverse when it collides in andengine

Tags: sprite, andengine, reverse

I am moving many AnimatedSprites randomly, but it overlapps with others.
How can i stop that overlapps & make sprite's moving reverse when it collides..?

or should I use another thing which can provide facility for move sprite when it collides...

Comment: Did you try anything already? What is your code for sprite movement and collision? Do you use sprite.collidesWith()?

Comment: i converted my code, now i moving sprite using body using Physics, but sprite moves only up & down, not left & right. so how can i solve this... i updated code in my question, take a look on it...

Comment: Ok, but you could just use collidesWith method of the entity. But box 2d may work as well

Comment: new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true){
  
    @Override
       public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
       {
           super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
                  
           
           if (face.getX() < 0) {
      body.setLinearVelocity(30, 0);
     } else if (face.getX() + face.getWidth() > CAMERA_WIDTH) {
      body.setLinearVelocity(-30, 0);
     }

     if (face.getY() < 0) {
      body.setLinearVelocity(0, 30);
     } else if (face.getY() + face.getHeight() > CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
      body.setLinearVelocity(0, -30);
     }           
       }
  });

Comment: actually, use of body solves my problem of moving in reverse when collides, bcoz body automatically moves it direction to another side, when it interact with other body.....bt the thing which is rest is body can move only two direction whether it's up & down or left & right, but i want all sides., so how can i achieve this....